# Parsing JSON from XmlHttpRequest.responseJSON

Tags: javascript, json, firefox-addon, bit.ly

I'm trying to parse a bit.ly JSON response in javascript.

I get the JSON via XmlHttpRequest.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest;  
req.overrideMimeType("application/json");  
req.open('GET', BITLY_CREATE_API + encodeURIComponent(url)
          + BITLY_API_LOGIN, true);  
var target = this;  
req.onload  = function() {target.parseJSON(req, url)};  
req.send(null);

parseJSON: function(req, url) {  
if (req.status == 200) {  
    var jsonResponse = req.responseJSON;  
    var bitlyUrl = jsonResponse.results[url].shortUrl;  
}
```

I do this in a firefox addon. When I run I get the error "jsonResponse is undefined" for the line `var bitlyUrl = jsonResponse.results[url].shortUrl;`. Am I doing anything wrong in parsing JSON here? Or what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 286, accepted):

**New ways I: `fetch`**

***TL;DR** I'd recommend this way as long as you don't have to send synchronous requests or support old browsers.*

A long as your request is asynchronous you can use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to send HTTP requests. The fetch API works with [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), which is a nice way to handle asynchronous workflows in JavaScript. With this approach you use `fetch()` to send a request and `ResponseBody.json()` to parse the response:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(jsonResponse) {
    // do something with jsonResponse
  });
```

You can use the `await` statement instead of the promise notation, to keep the code readable:

```
const response = await fetch(url);
const jsonResponse = await response.json();
// do something with jsonResponse
```

*Compatibility: The Fetch API is not supported by IE11 as well as Edge 12 & 13. However, there are [polyfills](https://github.com/github/fetch).*

**New ways II: `responseType`**

As [Londeren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/834003/londeren) has written in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45501836/398844), newer browsers allow you to use the `responseType` property to define the expected format of the response. The parsed response data can then be accessed via the `response` property:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.responseType = 'json';
req.open('GET', url, true);
req.onload  = function() {
   var jsonResponse = req.response;
   // do something with jsonResponse
};
req.send(null);
```

*Compatibility: `responseType = 'json'` is not supported by IE11.*

**The classic way**

The standard XMLHttpRequest has no `responseJSON` property, just `responseText` and `responseXML`. As long as bitly really responds with some JSON to your request, `responseText` should contain the JSON code as text, so all you've got to do is to parse it with `JSON.parse()`:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.overrideMimeType("application/json");
req.open('GET', url, true);
req.onload  = function() {
   var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
   // do something with jsonResponse
};
req.send(null);
```

*Compatibility: This approach should work with any browser that supports `XMLHttpRequest` and `JSON`.*

**JSONHttpRequest**

*Disclosure: I'm the owner of Pixels|Bytes. I thought that my script was a good solution for the original question, but it is rather outdated today. I do not recommend to use it anymore.*

If you prefer to use `responseJSON`, but want a more lightweight solution than JQuery, you might want to check out my JSONHttpRequest. It works exactly like a normal XMLHttpRequest, but also provides the `responseJSON` property. All you have to change in your code would be the first line:

```
var req = new JSONHttpRequest();
```

JSONHttpRequest also provides functionality to easily send JavaScript objects as JSON. More details and the code can be found here: http://pixelsvsbytes.com/2011/12/teach-your-xmlhttprequest-some-json/.

Comment: +1; IMO this was the real answer to the question - no jQuery just plain old vanilla ```XMLHttpRequest```; just what the question was about.

Comment: There`s a jquery version too. If you are getting crossbrowser issue`s try it, usually framework`s handle these problems better: 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: Four years later and this is still helping people.  :)  Linking to the blog is fine IMO, since it really is the full answer to the question with sample code and a download.  Thank you!

Comment: "Use a new library" is not as helpful as one might think.

Comment: @GrunionShaftoe Could you please explain, what do mean? I'm not suggesting to use a new library. My recommended solution `fetch` is standard JavaScript.

Comment: I find the `fetch(url).then(...).then(...)` notation quite cumbersome. An alternative is to create an `async` function and use `await`. A one-liner to answer the original question is `async () => { responseJson = (await fetch(url)).json() /* do something with responseJson */ }`. Alternatively, you can do something like `response = await fetch(url)` if you need the full response to check for example `response.ok` and the json can be extracted with `response.json()`. The caveat to `async` functions is that you are required to return a `Promise` if you have a return value.

Answer (score 37):

You can simply set `xhr.responseType = 'json';`

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    console.log('response', this.response); // JSON response  
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

[Documentation for responseType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType)

Comment: There's a major caveat here: neither IE, nor current versions of Edge support this (maybe Edge will finally after transitioning to Chromium)

Comment: Edge support added in v79

Answer (score 3):

Use [nsIJSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIJSON) if this is for a FF extension:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest;
req.overrideMimeType("application/json");
req.open('GET', BITLY_CREATE_API + encodeURIComponent(url) + BITLY_API_LOGIN, true);
var target = this;
req.onload = function() {target.parseJSON(req, url)};
req.send(null);

parseJSON: function(req, url) {
if (req.status == 200) {
  var jsonResponse = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/dom/json;1"]
      .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIJSON.decode(req.responseText);
  var bitlyUrl = jsonResponse.results[url].shortUrl;
}
```

For a webpage, just use `JSON.parse` instead of `Components.classes["@mozilla.org/dom/json;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIJSON.decode`

Answer (score 3):

Note: I've only tested this in Chrome.

it adds a prototype function to the XMLHttpRequest .. **XHR2**,

in **XHR** 1 you probably just need to replace `this.response` with `this.responseText`

```
Object.defineProperty(XMLHttpRequest.prototype,'responseJSON',{value:function(){
 return JSON.parse(this.response);
},writable:false,enumerable:false});
```

to return the json in xhr2

```
xhr.onload=function(){
 console.log(this.responseJSON());
}
```

EDIT

If you plan to use XHR with `arraybuffer` or other response types then you have to check if the response is a `string`.

in any case you have to add more checks e.g. if it's not able to parse the json.

```
Object.defineProperty(XMLHttpRequest.prototype,'responseJSON',{value:function(){
 return (typeof this.response==='string'?JSON.parse(this.response):this.response);
},writable:false,enumerable:false});
```

Comment: I would define a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) instead of a function attribute if I were you. Just replace `value` with `get` in the object passed to `Object.defineProperty`, and you can use `responseJSON` like you would any other response variable.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to include jQuery to use `responseJSON`.

Without jQuery, you could try with responseText and try like `eval("("+req.responseText+")");`

**UPDATE**:Please read the comment regarding `eval`, you can test with eval, but don't use it in working extension.

OR

use [json_parse](http://www.json.org/json_parse.js) : it does not use `eval`

Comment: For a Firefox addon running with chrome privs, don't try to eval anything you get from an outside source.  Instead, use JSON.parse (at least in FF 3.5 and later).