# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-chrome

I am trying to implement an AJAX contact form for my site, the problem I am encountering is that when I click on submit I get the following error in Google Chrome:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined----contact-form.js:38".
```

Please find [the HTML code](http://pastebin.com/QFwBcE0f) and [contact-from.js](http://pastebin.com/RM2TNFNX).

Comment: You should tag this with JavaScript, Chrome, AJAX, etc. so the right people see it.

Comment: Check the 'response.responseJSON' value if it's not null/undefined before accessing it: if(response.responseJSON) ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because `responseJSON` isn't a [standard property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or one [that jQuery makes available](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) for `XMLHttpRequest`s.

You'll want to [use `responseText` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973140/parsing-json-from-xmlhttprequest-responsejson), which [may be parsable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973140/parsing-json-from-xmlhttprequest-responsejson):

```
contactForm.addAjaxMessage($.parseJSON(response.responseText).message, true);

// or
contactForm.addAjaxMessage(response.responseText, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
error: function(response) {
     contactForm.addAjaxMessage(response.responseJSON.message, true);
}
```

If you take a look at the [jQuery documentation for `error` in `$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you'll see that the third parameter to the callback function is a string containing the error message:

> **error**
>
> `Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )`
>
> A function to be called if the request fails. The
>   function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x,
>   `XMLHttpRequest`) object, a string describing the type of error that
>   occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred.

So, try this, instead:

```
error: function(a, b, response) {
     // You can use `a` and `b` if you need them.

     contactForm.addAjaxMessage(response, true);
}
```