# Creating a simple web method to return a proper JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I'm trying to create a simple as possible web service with a single method that will return a proper `JSON`. Please, help me make this work instead of proposing `WCF`, `MVC` or other alternatives.
I'm aware of a possibility to write a manually serialized via `JavaScriptSerializer`(or other helpers and frameworks such as `DataContractJsonSerializer` or `Json.NET`) object directly to the `Response`. But as far as I understand the framework can do all the work by itself, and I just can't find the proper way of using it.
I've uncommented the `ScriptServiceAttribute`, and it seems that framework does it's job, but I get the JSON string with escaped quotes, and as result it cannot be evaluated into a usable object.
I understood that adding the `ScriptMethodAttribute` and specifying `ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json` to the method declaration is redundant, since it's set so by default for `ScriptServiceAttribute`, anyway adding it didn't help.
I've also tried to specify the return type as `object` and `IEnumerable<object>` but it didn't help either: casting to an `object` made the method unusable via standard browser test execution(by opening the URL of the service and launching the method) - the following error was returned

```
"System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] may not be used in this context."
```

while the later casting made the whole web service unusable with following error being generated

```
"Cannot serialize interface System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]."
```

---

Here are my steps:

1. File > New > Project : Installed > Templates > Visual C# > Web > ASP.NET Empty Web Application
2. Solution Explorer > Context Menu of the project from Step 1 > Add > New Item > Installed > Visual C# > Web >  Web Service

Here the code of my aspx.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace PlayGround
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Example
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Example : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public List<String> HelloWorld()
        {
            List<String> s = new List<string>();
            s.Add("q");
            s.Add("a");
            s.Add("z");
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Bellow is the content of web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Here is my test page JavaScript, again as simple as possible no jQuery, no nothing, just pure AJAX and synchronous execution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var jsO = null;
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

   request.open('Get', 'http://localhost:57560/Example.asmx?op=HelloWorld', false);
   request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   request.send(null);

   if ((request.readyState == 4) && (request.status == 200)) // Completed operation 
   {
       request.open("POST","http://localhost:57560/Example.asmx/HelloWorld", false);
       request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
       request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");

       try
       {
           request.send();
       }
       catch (e)
       {
           console.log(e);
       }

       jsO = eval(request.responseText); // Error: request.responseText = "{\"d\":[\"q\",\"a\",\"z\"]}"
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
jsO = eval(request.responseText);
```

to

```
jsO = eval("(" + request.responseText + ")");
```

see this prior question

[Parsing JSON from XmlHttpRequest.responseJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973140/parsing-json-from-xmlhttprequest-responsejson)

Comment: What are these parentheses do?

Comment: It turns it into an expression instead of trying to interpret it as a code block. See the following for an explanation. But as you've already figured out JSON.parse is better. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964397/why-does-javascripts-eval-need-parentheses-to-eval-json-data

Answer (score 0):

```
jsO = eval(request.responseText);
```

could be changed to:

```
jsO = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
```

Comment: I agree and it is actually more correct to parse than to eval.