# Problems with Reading JSON Files

Tags: javascript, json

So, I've been writing a webpage and for part of this project I needed to access a JSON file in the JavaScript code. So I wrote the following:

```
function xhrSuccess () { this.callback.apply(this, this.arguments); }
function xhrError () { console.error(this.statusTest); }

function loadFile(sUR) {
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.callback = readJSON;
    oReq.onload = xhrSuccess;
    oReq.onerror = xhrError;
    oReq.open("GET", sURL, true);
    oReq.send(null);
    return oReq.callback();
}

function readJSON() {
    console.log(this.responseText);
    var my_JSON_object = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    return my_JSON_object;
}
```

And it's called in this way:

```
var data = loadFile("http://localhost:8000/json/data.json");
```

But I keep getting a few errors, and I'm not sure as to their meaning or even why I'm getting them.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

The first error occurs when I try to parse my JSON.

I have no idea what this means at all, because it normally relates to some sort of misplaced semi-colon or related object that causes a literal syntax error but the error was caught at the `JSON.parse()` line so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Anyway, any help would be welcome.

And here's my JSON:

```
{ "data": [
     {"file": "temp", "title": "This is a test", "date": "August 21, 2015"},
     {"file": "temp2", "title": "This is also a test", "date": "August 20, 2015"},
    {"file": "temp3", "title": "This is the final test", "date": "August 22, 2015"}
] }
```

Comment: It means the data within `data.json` is not valid JSON in some way. Paste it into http://jsonlint.com/ to find out what's wrong

Comment: In order to generate valid JSON manually (if this is what you're doing), I usually build a standard js Object and then output the stringified result to console - then I copy and paste that JSON, to be sure it's valid.

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973140/parsing-json-from-xmlhttprequest-responsejson

This may solve your problem.

Comment: By default, if there is no `return` statement in a function, then the function returns `undefined`. Here, `loadFile` doesn't contain any return statement, so it returns undefined: that's why your `data` variable is undefined. The data is only accessible in the `readJSON` function ;)

Comment: @RGraham Thanks for the comment. I checked and jsonlint.com said it was valid.

Comment: @pawanbhardwaj But I'm referencing `responseText` not `responseJSON` so that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: @Brunt In that case, what should `loadFile` return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to parse a JSON object that is not stringified, you'll get `Unexpected token` errors. Are you sure the JSON content you get is stringified?

Next, you return `oReq.callback();` in your loadFile function. When calling loadFile later on (`var data = loadFile("http://localhost:8000/json/data.json");`), the line `return oReq.callback();` is immediately executed so the value of `this.responseText` is empty string (`""`) by the time readJSON is executed, that's why you should get an error like "Unexpected end of input" (because `JSON.parse('')` raises that error).

One way of doing it is to process your data directly in the readJSON function because that's where your data (after the **asynchronous** request is resolved) will be. But this can lead to poor code quality if you have to make one/several requests later on with the data of your first request:

```
var xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr1.onload = function (req) {
  var data = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
  var postId = data.posts[0].id;
  var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr2.onload = function (req2) {
    // imagine if we sill have 2 more requests before getting the data needed...
  };
  xh2.open('GET', 'http://example.com/posts/' + postId, true);
  xh2.send();
};
xhr1.open('GET', 'http://example.com/users/1', true);
xhr1.send();
```

This callback architecture is called "the Pyramid of Doom". Nowadays, we have tools that let us write better code for these use cases, for example [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise). It's currently in draft (part of ES6/ES2015 specification), not all browsers support it, but you can use polyfills or libraries/frameworks that implement it (e.g. $.ajax from jQuery, $q from AngularJS, Promise from babel-polyfill...).

In your case, we can use the babel-polyfill from [Babel](http://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#subclassable-built-ins). First, you need to include the polyfills before your Javascript code, for example using the cdnjs.com link:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser-polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

Then, your code will look like this:

```
function loadData(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onload = function onload(request) {
      if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        resolve(data);
      } else {
        // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
        reject(Error('Could not load any data'));
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function onerror(err) {
      reject(err);
    };

    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send();
  });
}

loadData('http://example.com')
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log('Got the data!', data);
    // do something with the data..., for example, if data is a stringified json:
    return JSON.parse(data);
  }, function (err) {
    console.log('There was an error', err);
  })
  .then(function (parsedJson) {
    console.log('Parsed JSON', parsedJson);
  });
```

[Link to the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HNCvNsS9VJgjSBfl7al8?p=preview).

There are tons of guides/tutorials about asynchronous requests and promises on the web, I suggest you reading about it! ;)

Comment: Ok thanks. This fixes the errors, but it does lead to a new problem but I don't think this is with my code and it's off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

The uncaught SyntaxError means that the JSON you are about to parse it not properly formatted.

Where are you setting `this.responseText`? I think you should instead use `sMsg.responseText`. Perhaps adding more surrounding code to your question can clarify this.

Comment: I added the JSON file I'm using but there's really nothing else to this. When I put the JSON into a string and call the parse from another function it works fine but when I try to pull it from the .json file there's problems. However, the JSON itself is logged to the console just fine so I don't see the problem.

Comment: Are you using a NodeJS server or something similar to deliver the JSON? Have you checked in your browsers console, that `http://localhost:8000/json/data.json` is in fact the content of `data.json`? Perhaps you have an issue with file type (should be `application/json`) or line feeds (should be the correct one for your OS).

Comment: Yes, `http://localhost:8000/json/data.json` actually navigates to the file itself; I checked in my browser. As for the server, I set up one using a python command. Not sure what you mean by file type or line feed issues. Could you be more specific?