# Can you get node js to send an array not a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, response

I want the code to return a 2d array of the results.
E.g.
clothes = [[1,"name","desc"],[2,"name2","desc2"]]
can you make res send a list or do you have to make a list once you have returned it?

```
app.get('/post', (req, res) => {
    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var query = "SELECT * FROM products"
        con.query(query, function (err, results, fields) {
          if (err) throw err;
          var clothes = [];
          Object.keys(results).forEach(function(key) {
            let r = []
            var row = results[key];
            r.push(row.ID);
            r.push(row.name);
            r.push(row.link);
            r.push(row.imageLink);
            r.push(row.type);
            r.push(row.colour);
            r.push(row.price);
            r.push(row.brand);
            clothes.push(r);
          });  
        res.send(clothes);
  });
  });
  
});
```

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    
    clothes = this.response;
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = clothes;
    
  };
  
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000/post", true);
  xhttp.send();
```

Comment: You need to send a JSON then, and treat it on the client as such. To send: `res.json(clothes)`. And on the client you need to parse it: `JSON.parse(this.response)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course.

Check out the official [NodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html)

Example:

```js
app.get('/post', (req, res) => {
    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var query = "SELECT * FROM products"
        con.query(query, function (err, results, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var clothes = [];
            ...
            // Better set the header so the client knows what to expect; safari requires this
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.end(JSON.stringify(clothes));
        });
    });
});
```

#### You seem to be using the [expresjs framework](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

Here you have a convenience method to do the above:

```js
...
    con.query(query, function (err, results, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var clothes = [];
        res.json(clothes);
    });
...
```

#### Read the response on the client side

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8416963/11641932) is a good answer on how to do this.

In short: It is recommended to use the new `fetch()` method on client side.

```js
fetch("http://localhost:3000/post")
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(clothes) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = clothes;
  });
```

Comment: Also, in the future you might want to render an html element with child elements like `<div class="product"><div class="product-image"></div><div class="product-name"></div></div` or something for each product which gets into hell of vanilla js, so you might want to consider using a Virtual DOM/component library/framework like React (Easiest to setup and learn in my opinion), Vue or Angular (Hardest to learn).